# Simple multiplication app in Android

Tags: android, multiplication

So like so many others i am new to android. I have looked everywhere for an explanation of how to do this but have found none.
this is the app im trying to make. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGhJP.png

Im assuming i have to take the input from the top two edittexts and put them into stings and them multiply them and set that answers equal to the bottom edittext? 
Im just confused as to how i would correctly do that. 
Here is what ive tried so far.

```
  package com.wattzen.testcalculation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Main extends Activity {

private static final String total_Made = "total_Made";

private double tmmade;
private int hedittext;
private int etmade;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        tmmade = 0.0;

    } else {
        tmmade = savedInstanceState.getDouble(total_Made);
    }
}
    {

{
    hedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ethours);
    etmade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmade);
    etmade.addTextChangedListener(etmadeWatcher);}

}

private void updateStandard() {
    double tmmade = hedittext * etmade;
    tmmade.addTextChangedListener(tmmadeWatcher);
    double toTal= tmmade;
}

}
```

and here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hours Worked" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ethours"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="Amount made per hour" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etmade"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bcalculate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Calculate" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Total Money Made" />

    </TableRow>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tmmade"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="number" />

</TableLayout>
```

I greatly appreciate any help you guys can give me. thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a TableLayout inside a RelativeLayout? Keep it simple... use just the RelativeLayout. In a better way, you could use a LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting a ton of syntax errors that should clue you in on lines that need changing.

Since hedittext and etmade are ints, you cannot set them equal to an EditText, as you do in onCreate().

First you need to get the actual content of the EditTexts. You can do this by calling the edit text's [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) methods. 
Then you need to parse the result of getText as an integer. You can do this using the Integer wrapper class' [parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method.

It should look more like this:

```
EditText editTextA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ethours);
int hours = Integer.parseInt(editTextA.getText().toString())
```

Comment: Ah i see. When working with parsing the result of the getText as an integer do i need to make a string for that in my xml or will it automatically create one?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Strings in your xml values should be used when you are displaying text to the user (such as the content of a popup or the text on a button). Doing so makes localization far simpler and keeps all your Strings in one convenient location. This string is never seen by the user, so you don't need to worry about localization.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to assign an onClick listener the calculate button. Once you do this, reference both the editTexts within onCreate. After this, you can get the text from the edit texts using the **getText()** function.

Here is a basic mockup of the code. Id suggest checking if the input is valid first and then multiplying

```
Button bcalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bcalculate);
EditText hedittext   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ethours);
EditText etmade   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etmade);
EditText tmmade   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext3);

bcalculate.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
           try{ 
            double e1 = Double.parseDouble(hedittext.getText().toString());
            double e2 = Double.parseDouble(etmade.getText().toString());
            tmmade.setText(e1*e2);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }

    });
```

Comment: okay i will try that. Should i be using doubles and not ints?

Comment: @Wattzen yes, some users may work 8.5 hours or being making 12.50 an hour. If you multiply those you will get a decimal so using double is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped me out. The only issue i have now is that there is an error with tmmade.setText(e1*e2); eclipse wants me to define them as ints instead of doubles?

Comment: more specifically.."The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for 
 the arguments (double)"